# HTML5 pointermove/touchmove not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, canvas, microsoft-edge

I'm working on something which is more or less a drawing app. I need to support Microsoft Edge and there's the problem. As soon as you want to catch the touchmove or pointermove event, Edge tries to scroll (even if it's not possible). [Here's an example](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/). Just try to draw something there (touch/pen), mouse works perfectly even in Edge. In every other browser (except maybe IE) it works very well.

I have no idea why IE is ignoring the preventDefault() function. Has someone an idea?

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/ryqagkeb/

Actually doesn't work with my Surface Pro & Surface Pen on Chrome and Edge.

```
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
start = 0;
canvas.onpointerdown = function(evt) {
    start = 1;
}

canvas.onpointermove = function(evt) {
    if(start) {
        ctx.fillRect(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 5,5);
    }
}

canvas.onpointerup = function(evt) {
    start = 0;
}
```

Comment: it might be a propagation thing, have you tried `e.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: Please include an [mcve] inside your question as an [edit]. We need to see your actual code in order to determine what can be wrong in it if anything. A link to a broad tuto is not enough.

Comment: I've added an example. It works when using mouse, but stops working when you use touch or pen input :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I think I've found the solution myself and posting it now because I think it's pretty helpful. It seems the CSS property "touch-action" can solve the problem.

Setting:

```
canvas {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

It seems like it fixes the problem.

Comment: I have tried this approach, using pointermove event on DIV - however yet not working. The scenario is pointerdown creates the DIV (fill up the screen) which holds the pointermove event - however: The pointermove have no reaction - tested on Safari