# How to use touch events in IE and Edge?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, touch, microsoft-edge

I am trying to get touch (and digitizer) events to work in IE and Edge. However, these browsers always send the touch events to the browser UI instead of the dom element. I tried to prevent this with the usual

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

but with no success.

Here is a pen where one should be able to draw with touch on a SVG canvas but it only works with Firefox and Chrome.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYwWyJ

It can be checked that it works otherwise properly with IE and Edge by replacing 'touchmove' with 'mousemove' and removing '.changedTouches[0]'.

Interestingly, other pages have the same problems, for example,

- http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/smoothing-simplifying-flattening/
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_touchmove2

I hope I am not out of luck but this must be working somehow with at least Edge I hope.

**Edit**

I found a similar question (not a duplicate because it deals with different events) here:

- [HTML5 pointermove/touchmove not working in Microsoft Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299496/html5-pointermove-touchmove-not-working-in-microsoft-edge)

However, the suggested solution does work neither in the case it is suggested for nor in my case.

Comment: I just found a workaround (solution?): Using `touch-action: none;`, as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305956/1981832, on the svg element and using `mousemove` instead of `touchmove`, as explained in my question, seems to do the trick in IE and Edge. Here is a pen that works in both: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxREwR.